# Creating a schedule for an example task set with non-preemptive Deadline Monotonic (fixed priority) scheduling

Tags: algorithm, real-time, scheduler, scheduling, preemptive

In the effort of trying to understand a fixed priority scheduling scheme, such as Deadline Monotonic schedulers, amidst the horribly written definitions online -- I'm trying to schedule an example task set with that policy, in which I **require** that the execution of tasks is non-preemptive. This means that I have the following assumptions:

1. When a task begins executing, it cannot be stopped by any other task, so the former must finish
2. The tasks in the task set are released periodically (according to period `Ti`)
3. All tasks are first released at time t=0
4. Each task task_i has a fixed computation time `Ci`
5. Each task task_i has a relative deadline `Di`, which is relative to the time in which the task came in (was released)

Assume I have this task set:

- Task 1: `C1 = 1`, `D1 = 2`, `T1 = 3`
- Task 2: `C2 = 1`, `D2 = 5`, `T2 = 5`
- Task 3: `C3 = 2`, `D3 = 5`, `T3 = 5`

According to the exact schedulability test based on worst case response time analysis from [Theorem 15 by George et al.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281567091_Preemptive_and_Non-Preemptive_Real-Time_UniProcessor_Scheduling), the task set is in fact schedulable.

To create the schedule for a supposed interval of time `[0, 10]`, this means that:

- Task 1 becomes available at the instances: 0, 3, 6, 9
- Task 2 becomes available at the instances: 0, 5, 10
- Task 3 becomes available at the instances: 0, 5, 10

With deadline monotonic scheduling, we already know that task_1 >= task_2 >= task_3 according to priority, since the deadline of task_1 <= that of task_2 <= that of task_3.

**I will first try to formulate the schedule for each discrete interval, and then ask a follow-up question on the problematic interval:**

```
# interval  ->  executing task
[0, 1] -> task_1
[1, 2] -> task_2
[2, 3] -> task_3
[3, 4] -> task_3
[4, 5] -> task_1
[5, 6] -> task_2
[6, 7] -> I THINK, task_1
```

So at instance `t=6`, two tasks are ready: task_1 and task_3.
Is it correct that task_1 should get the priority and execute between instances 6 and 7 -- or should task_3 execute since we always do: task_1 then task_2 then task_3?

If it is the case that the higher priority task would execute, then wouldn't this imply that we HAVE to re-sort a queue of pending tasks every time a new task arrives?

If so, doesn't that defy the purpose and then a fixed priority scheduler would actually be dynamic in nature?

Comment: A priority scheduler is always a form of sorting.  In the simplest case, the dispatcher merely chooses the task at the head of a sorted (priority) queue.  When a task becomes runnable, it is inserted in the priority queue in order.  Now, it happens that with a small number of priorities, you can use fancy cpu instructions on a bitfield to detect the next highest priority task, thus the O(n) insertion time becomes O(1), but that is a special purpose hack, not a general implementation.

Comment: @mevets So I guess that the (re-sorting) and selection of the next available task with highest priority has to be done after every task has finished executing?

Comment: Yes, the selection is generally O(1) -- even with a simple priority-q, it is just removing the head.  The insertion would be O(n); but could be worked around.   It is possible to encode a table with the activations so that the dispatch merely went `for (i = 0; ; i = (i + 1) % NTAB) {  Dispatch(tab[i]); }`  where tab[i] encodes the schedule you have above.  It would be a tidy implementation, while equivalent to priority encoding, thus theory.